# Imagesarray double when i back from detailview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

```
I parse xml images urls from tableview to detailview when xml format is like 

so I wrote like this
```

In below code the some content  so i wrote the code like this.

this is another type of tag so wrote code like

```
if ([elementObj isEqualToString:@"media:thumbnail"]) {

            [Imagesarray addObject:attributeDict[@"url"]];
}
```

In foundcharactor i dont use this because i got the array here

```
[Imagesarray addObject:attributeDict[@"url"]];
```

When i didnot use this in didendelement method because it does not have the attributedstring

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    elementObj = elementName;

    if ([elementObj isEqualToString:@"media:thumbnail"]) {

        [Imagesarray addObject:attributeDict[@"url"]];



        NSLog(@"%@ it is images array",Imagesarray);
    }

    if ([elementObj isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        _item    = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        titleObj   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        pubdataObj= [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        DiscriptionObj=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
        }
   }
```

When i click on back button of the detail view all the images add to the array again.How can i write code for this.
    Please help me.

```
    -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string

    {

        if ([elementObj isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
            [titleObj appendString:string];
        }
        else if ([elementObj isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]) {
            [pubdataObj appendString:string];
        }
        else if ([elementObj isEqualToString:@"description"]){
            [DiscriptionObj appendString:string];

    -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
    {
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

            [_item setObject:titleObj forKey:@"title"];
            [_item setObject:pubdataObj forKey:@"pubDate"];
             [_item setObject:DiscriptionObj forKey:@"description"];
            [feedsArry addObject:_item];
           [];   
        }
   }
```

Comment: What is your quesiton ?

Comment: You can check the url string within the array before inserting. The problem may be here that your parser start parsing again and again.

Comment: ya that is the issue.in the issue i wrote that and how can write code in didend element.if i wrote in didendelement the array will not resave.

Comment: where do you start your parser? in viewDidAppear by chance?

Comment: i am using the data in viewwillappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking whether you are parsing the array from viewdidappear or viewwillappear method. if yes this method will be called whenever the view is opened. it would be better to move parsing to viewdidload which will be called only once when the view is loading.

Comment: i am using view will appear